# How can I export my "Computers & Contacts" from TeamViewer?

Tags: windows, backup, export, teamviewer, contacts

I am trying to save my "Computers & Partners" from TeamViewer due to an account migration. So far, I wasn't able to save the list offline. 
Typing all the contacts by hand will be the last resort, but I thought that I should ask the experts first.

There is an Export-function under Advanced Options, which creates a .reg file but there are no real contact details in there.

**1) TeamViewer Export Option**

[image: Export Option]

**2) Say What**

[image: Say What]

**3) Nothing Meaningful**

[image: Nothing Meaningful]

If it matters: TeamViewer 11 on Windows

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no way to Export the Computers and Contacts, but there is a way to 'share' them.
If you have more than one account that you want to 'merge', login to the 'secondary' account and add the 'primary account' as Contact.  You can then Share Groups of Computers with the Primary contact with either Read, Read Write, or Full Control.  ( I used Full Control )
The Primary account will get some emails requiring it to be accepted as a contact, and add the Shared Group.
Once those have all been accepted, then login in as the Primary account and you will see the Shared groups from the Secondary account.

At this point you can then actually go into each of the shared groups and select them and Move them to a Primary account Group.

Hope this helps

Comment: Still relevant, helped me today

Answer (score 1):

I've just figured it out:
Select your `Computer/Contact` entries in the list with your mouse (click on the first element, then press <kbd>Shift</kbd> and click on the last),
then drag your selection into any folder opened in the Explorer.
It'll create a handy link for each `Computer/Contact` entry.

Comment: nice, but how do you re-import them?

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

1)Log into your old account on https://login.teamviewer.com/LogOn
2)Go to Add contact, enter your new Teamviewer sign-in email address, skip the group and click add contact.
3)Highlight your group on the left-hand side and click toolsshare group and add your newly added contact.
4)set permissions to full control and save.
Note: Repeat steps 2-4 for multiple groups
5)You will receive mail notifications about the newly shared group with a link, click the link to add the group to your new account. (Note: These notification mail links are for each individual group, so expect multiple emails for multiple groups)
6)Log in to the Teamviewer app with your new credentials.
7)All computers will be shared with your new Teamviewer account.
Note: If you have groups, create new Groups on the new account and move computers from the shared computers to the new group.

NB!! When moving from the old account to the new account, on the old side the computers will be completely removed from this account